# Автоматическое изменение высоты линии

Tags: css

Есть сайдбар - линия (показана на рисунке). Интересует вот что: как сделать так, чтобы эта линия автоматически меняла высоту при добавлении постов или какого-то текста в сайдбар?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="div_with_text"></div>
```

CSS:

Если колонка справа:

```
#div_with_text {
border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

Для левой колонки:

```
#div_with_text {
border-right: 1px solid #808080;
}
```